# How to define a new Java class and create its instances at runtime?

Tags: java, dynamic, orm, runtime, metaclass

I want to define a new Java class at runtime using some input information, for instance, from `Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));` and then map objects of this class to relational database via some `ORM` or persistence API (`MyBatis`, `Hibernate`). Is it even possible to do this and if yes how to achieve this (what libraries, tools etc.)? My own idea is to use [Jython](https://wiki.python.org/jython/UserGuide) [metaclasses](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Metaclasses),  but I think there are simpler solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [The Compiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html)

here is an example - http://www.accordess.com/wpblog/an-overview-of-java-compilation-api-jsr-199/

Comment: you might have issues with any existing SessionFactory in hibernate / EntityManagerFactory in jpa, as those do a lot of binding at instantiation time, and typically don't have a way to register classes after instantiation time.  In those cases, you might have to reconstruct your SessionFactory/EntityManagerFactory

Comment: Depends on how your instantiating it.  A typical use case is to use spring to do it for you with LocalSessionFactoryBean class.  This internally creates a Configuration object and uses that to construct the SessionFactory via the "buildSessionFactory" method.  So if you want to add classes on the fly as you've suggested, you need to rebuild the Configuration object, add the new class and then rebuild the SessionFactory.  This means any references to the old one (typically in dao classes) would not have the new class mapped (plus this might present transaction management issues as well).

Comment: ps:  there are workaround to this, one of which might involve using a dynamic proxy which would delegate to the SessionFactory.  You could then rebuild the underlying SessionFactory and tell the proxy to delegate it's methods there.  But, that involves a bunch of work, and might be too complex a solution for some people.